# Strange behaviour of STM32F407 while writhing to CAN_BTR register

Tags: cpu-registers, stm32f4

I defined following user type:

```
typedef struct
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint32_t BRP :10;
            uint32_t Reserved_1 :6;
            uint32_t TS1 :4;
            uint32_t TS2 :3;
            uint32_t Reserved_2 :1;
            uint32_t SJW :2;
            uint32_t Reserved_3 :4;
            uint32_t LBKM :1;
            uint32_t SILM :1;

        };
        uint32_t reg;
    };
}__attribute__((packed, aligned(1))) _CAN_BTR;
```

Then created variable:

```
_CAN_BTR *CAN_BTR = (_CAN_BTR*) &(CAN->BTR);
```

But when wrighting with following code i get wrong results:

```
CAN_BTR->TS1 = 9;
CAN_BTR->TS2 = 4;
CAN_BTR->BRP = 6;
CAN_BTR->SJW = 3;
```

At the end it seems like problem in the wrighting to register, because everithing is fine until

```
strb    r3, [r2, #2]
```

where **r3** hold correct value **r2** holds base address of CAN_BTR register and #2 ossfet pionts to third byte of register which holds TS1 value.

After some experiments with asm i figureg out that for some reason

```
strb    r3, [r2, #2]
```

always modifyes first (offset 0) and third (offset 2) byte of that register. With local varible there is no such problem.

CAN_BTR default value is **0x1230000** and aftar any of following instructons

```
strb    r3, [r2, #0]
strb    r3, [r2, #1]
strb    r3, [r2, #2]
strb    r3, [r2, #3]
```

it became **0x1290129**.

Is there any hardware bug or restriction which i dont know of? I checked out errata for STM32F407 but there nothing about something similar in CAN section.

Thanks in advance for answers.

***UPDATE**

There is more about code - disassembly listnig:

```
 79       CAN_BTR->TS1 = 9;
080006da:   ldr     r2, [r7, #16]
080006dc:   ldrb    r3, [r2, #2]
080006de:   movs    r1, #9
080006e0:   bfi     r3, r1, #0, #4
080006e4:   strb    r3, [r2, #2]
 80       CAN_BTR->TS2 = 4;
080006e6:   ldr     r2, [r7, #16]
080006e8:   ldrb    r3, [r2, #2]
080006ea:   movs    r1, #4
080006ec:   bfi     r3, r1, #4, #3
080006f0:   strb    r3, [r2, #2]
 81       CAN_BTR->BRP = 6;
080006f2:   ldr     r3, [r7, #16]
080006f4:   movs    r2, #0
080006f6:   orr.w   r2, r2, #6
080006fa:   strb    r2, [r3, #0]
080006fc:   ldrb    r2, [r3, #1]
080006fe:   bic.w   r2, r2, #3
08000702:   strb    r2, [r3, #1]
 82       CAN_BTR->SJW = 3;
08000704:   ldr     r2, [r7, #16]
08000706:   ldrb    r3, [r2, #3]
08000708:   orr.w   r3, r3, #3
0800070c:   strb    r3, [r2, #3]
```

Before first line register have default value **0x1230000**.
After this line

```
080006e4:   strb    r3, [r2, #2]
```

register value is **0x1290129**.

Is there any more code i need to show to illustrate my problem?

***UPDATE 2**

Now type defined as:

```
typedef struct
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint32_t BRP :10;
            uint32_t  :6;
            uint32_t TS1 :4;
            uint32_t TS2 :3;
            uint32_t  :1;
            uint32_t SJW :2;
            uint32_t  :4;
            uint32_t LBKM :1;
            uint32_t SILM :1;

        };
        uint32_t reg;
    };
} _CAN_BTR;
```

but this lead to identical asm code:

```
 86       CAN_BTR->TS1 = 9;
08000718:   ldr     r2, [r7, #16]
0800071a:   ldrb    r3, [r2, #2]
0800071c:   movs    r1, #9
0800071e:   bfi     r3, r1, #0, #4
08000722:   strb    r3, [r2, #2]
```

***SOULTION**

As pionetd out by [0___________](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6110094/0) problem was in accessing CAN register as bytes, but reference manual permits only word(32bit) acess. Thanks!

Comment: See my amended answer. Your packing and aligning is wrong. Remove it and it will work correctly

Answer (score 1):

The CAN registers **HAVE** to be accessed as words. Your code is accessing them as bytes, which is **INVALID**

Do not introduce pointers as it has a performance penalty.

`}__attribute__((packed, aligned(1)))` _CAN_BTR; alignment makes no sense. Packing is not needed and will emit very inefficient code and also forces byte access which is invalid!!!

You do not need to name bitfield padding.

```
typedef struct
{
    union
    {
        struct
        {
            uint32_t BRP :10;
            uint32_t  :6;
            uint32_t TS1 :4;
            uint32_t TS2 :3;
            uint32_t  :1;
            uint32_t SJW :2;
            uint32_t  :4;
            uint32_t LBKM :1;
            uint32_t SILM :1;
        };
        uint32_t reg;
    };
}_CAN_BTR;
```

```
#define MYCAN_BTR ((volatile _CAN_BTR *)(&CAN -> BTR))
```

and access bitfields without introducing any overhead.

```
MYCAN_BTR -> SJW = ....
```

**UPDATE** If your compiler generates this code you need to do it different way.

```
#define MODIFY_CAN_BTR(field,val) do{_CAN_BTR btr = CAN->BTR; btr -> field = val; CAN -> BTR = btr -> reg;}while(0)
```

Comment: `#define MYCAN_BTR ((volatile _CAN_BTR *)(&CAN -> BTR))` and `MYCAN_BTR->TS1 = 9; `produses same: `CAN -> BTR = 0x1290129`

Comment: @Erelwar did you remove the attribute?

Comment: @Erelwar see my amended answer

Comment: Looks like compiler will use byte access even for unpacked structs until variable is not volatile. After making it volatile it uses `str` instead of `strb` and there's no problem with modifying.

Comment: @Erelwar I use volatile when is needed. If you ignore what I wrote is simply a waste of my time ....

Comment: Thanks for your answers! Can you point out where i can read about that byte access to peripheral registers is forbidden?

Comment: Thanks again. You helped alot.